# Input and Output to the lstms in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to implement lstms with CNN in pytorch as my data is a time series data i.e. frames of video for heart rate detection, I am struggling with the input and output dimensions for lstms what and how i should properly configure the dimensions/parameters/arguments at input of lstms in pytorch as its quite confusing when considering time steps, hidden state etc.
my output from CNN is “2 batches of 256 frames”, which is now the input to lstms
batch is 2
features =256
the output is also a batch of 2 with 256 frames.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the input shape of sequential data takes the form `(batch_size, seq_len, num_features)`. Based on your explanation, I assume your input is of the form `(2, 256)`, where 2 is the batch size and 256 is the sequence length of scalars (1-dimensional tensor). Therefore, you should reshape your input to be `(2, 256, 1)` by `inputs.unsqueeze(2)`.

To declare and use an LSTM model, simply try

```py
from torch import nn

model = nn.LSTM(
    input_size=1, # 1-dimensional features
    batch_first=True, # batch is the first (zero-th) dimension
    hidden_size=some_hidden_size, # maybe 64, 128, etc.
    num_layers=some_num_layers, # maybe 1 or 2
    proj_size=1, # output should also be 1-dimensional
)
outputs, (hidden_state, cell_state) = model(inputs)
```

Comment: Thank You yes is like that I have figured out too, but what about the  dimension of hidden_state and cell_state and the output is different from hidden_state

Comment: Hey, the [PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) is pretty comprehensive and I recommend that you check it out. To answer your follow up, `hidden_state.shape == (d * num_layers, proj_size)`, and `cell_state.shape == (d * num_layers, hidden_size)`.